# Why is an NSString making my Release version crash but inside of Xcode it works?

Tags: xcode, crash, nsstring

My program pulls in a C style string from a file, converts it to an NSString and places it in an NSMutableArray.  Every time I run the program, either Debug or Release version, in XCode it runs perfectly.  However every time I run it outside of XCode it crashes and the report says "-[NSPlaceholderString initWithString:]: nil argument'".  This is the line of code where the problem occurs.

```
input = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:data->acctNames]] mutableCopy];
```

I have also tried this:

```
input = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:data->acctNames];
```

Can anyone explain what is wrong with this?

Comment: What about `input = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", data->acctNames];`?

Comment: @aroth I didn't even see your reply before. It works perfectly now! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the file you are opening doesn't exist and the string is not being initialized.  You should look at the file path and see if it is an absolute path.  Maybe you are trying to open the file in a local directory and the file doesn't exist in the run directory after you have built the binary.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought but the files are created if they don't exist. And when I check it after running the app they're there.